# Two arrays of objects and need to sort one based on the other

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of objects like this

```
var array1 = [
  {
   "key": 0,
   "display": "hide",
  },
  {
   "key": 1,
   "display": "show",
  },
  {
   "key": 2,
   "display": "show",
  },
 ]

var array2 = [
 {
  "key": 1,
  "question": "some text here",
 },
 {
  "key": 0,
  "question": "Different text here",
 },
 {
  "key": 2,
  "question": "Even more different",
 },
]
```

I need array1 to be reordered to match the order of the keys in array2, not just update the key to match the order but the display value would need to update (so move/reorder the whole object)

For example after sorting array1 to match the order of array2 keys I'd expected array1 to result in:

```
[
 {
  "key": 1,
  "display": "show",
 },
 {
  "key": 0,
  "display": "hide",
 },
 {
  "key": 2,
  "display": "show",
 }
]
```

I know it's probably done using the sort function but I'm having a hard time understanding how it would work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by:

```js
var array1 = [ { "key": 0, "display": "hide", }, { "key": 1, "display": "show", }, { "key": 2, "display": "show", }];
var array2 = [ { "key": 1, "question": "some text here", }, { "key": 0, "question": "Different text here", }, { "key": 2, "question": "Even more different", }];

var keys = array2.map(el => el.key);
array1.sort((a, b) => keys.indexOf(a.key) - keys.indexOf(b.key));
console.log(array1);
```

Comment: Simple and efficient. Don't fiddle with hash maps unless you really have to.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a hashMap, that will hold index values and based on it, you can sort array.

```js
var array1 = [ { "key": 0, "display": "hide", }, { "key": 1, "display": "show", }, { "key": 2, "display": "show", },]

var array2 = [ { "key": 1, "question": "some text here", }, { "key": 0, "question": "Different text here", }, { "key": 2, "question": "Even more different", },]

var array2Hash = array2.reduce(function(p,c,i){
  p[c.key] = i;
  return p;
}, Object.create(null))

array1.sort(function(a,b){
  return array2Hash[a.key] - array2Hash[b.key];
});

console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably approach it by building a map of the keys to indexes of the first array, then using that map when sorting the second, see comments:

```js
var array1 = [ { "key": 0, "display": "hide", }, { "key": 1, "display": "show", }, { "key": 2, "display": "show", },]

var array2 = [ { "key": 1, "question": "some text here", }, { "key": 0, "question": "Different text here", }, { "key": 2, "question": "Even more different", },]

// Build the map of key->index from the first array
var map = Object.create(null);
array1.forEach(function(entry, index) {
  map[entry.key] = index;
});
// Sort the second array using the key->index map
// map[left.key] - map[right.key] returns a number less than 0
// if the left should be before the right, 0 if they're the
// the same (they won't be, as these are indexes from the
// first array), or greater than zero if the left should be
// after the right
array2.sort(function(left, right) {
  return map[left.key] - map[right.key];
});
console.log(array2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Any advantage of using `Object.create(null)` instead of `{}` or `new Object()` ?

Comment: @Rayon: For the keys in the quoted data, no. In general, when using objects as maps, it's useful to avoid having the properties from `Object.prototype` showing up on them, so I'm in the habit of using `Object.create(null)` to create an object with no prototype (and thus no pre-existing inherited properties). But it doesn't matter in the above, `map = {};` would be fine.

Comment: I have replaced data with minified version so that emphasis remains on the logic. If you think the edit is not required, please revert it

Comment: @Rajesh: Thanks, great edit. I thought about doing that but then a bright shiny object just have captured my....oooh, what's that?

Comment: @VedranMaricevic.: My issue with that answer was that it didn't tell the OP what was wrong with their code, and instead just completely wrote a whole new solution with zero explanation. Perhaps we (myself, Rajesh, etc.) shouldn't have answered this question with the OP not having posted an attempt, but it's a fine line, and I **did** explain. So for me, no, not the same thing. (Thanks for the reminder, I meant to go remove that once I was sure she'd seen it, as it has no enduring value.)